# Modeling Device Relationships

Tags: sql-server, c#

At currently I am designing an inventory system for internal use and I have come across an interesting scenario when adding tables for creating the devices. Currently I have tables for Device, DeviceMake, DeviceModel and DeviceCategory. I am stuck now as to how I should define the relationship between these tables. I was  thinking of using them as orphan tables but I am not sure if in the long run that will prove problematic, versus having some sort of many to many relationships or otherwise. Each device should belong to a category, each device should have a Make and a Model should be found under a specific Make. For example,

```
Device Category [ Laptop, Mouse, Keyboard, etc...]
Make [ Samsung, HP, Dell, Logitech, etc...]
Model [ S9, Prodesk, XPS1200 ]

public class AssetCategory
{
    [Key]
    public int AssetCategoryId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Asset> Assets { get; set; }
}

public class Asset
{
    [Key]
    public int AssetId { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Assignment Status")]
    public AssignedStatus AssignmentStatus { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Serial Number")]
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public AssetCondition Condition { get; set; }


    public double Price { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Device Make")]
    public int? AssetMakeId { get; set; }
    public AssetMake AssetMake { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Device Model")]
    public int? AssetModelId { get; set; }
    public AssetModel AssetModel { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Device Category")]
    public int AssetCategoryId { get; set; }
    public AssetCategory AssetCategory { get; set; }


    public string Remarks { get; set; }

    //Mappings
    public virtual ICollection<AssetHistory> AssetHistory {get;set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AssetAssignments> AssetAssignments {get;set; }


    public enum AssetCondition
    {
        Good = 1,
        Dead = 2,
        Damaged = 3,
        Repairing = 4,
    }

    public enum AssignedStatus
    {
        Assigned = 2,
        Unassigned = 1
    }
}

public class AssetModel
{
    [Key]
    public int AssetModelId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    //public int AssetMakeId { get; set; }
    //public AssetMake AssetMake { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Asset> Assets { get; set; }
}

public class AssetMake
{
    [Key]
    public int AssetMakeId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MinLength(3,ErrorMessage = "Too short")]
    [MaxLength(300,ErrorMessage = "Too long")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //public int AssetModelId { get; set; }
    //public AssetModel AssetModel { get; set; }

    //public ICollection<AssetModel> Models { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Asset> Assets { get; set; }
}
```

What is the recommended way to represent this relationship in SQL?